# Does SQL Azure support the FILESTREAM datatype

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am looking at using SQL Azure and wondering if it supports the FILESTREAM data type introduced int SQL Server 2008 or should I look at another solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it does not: [Azure SQL Database Transact-SQL Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336281.aspx)

Comment: A more up to date link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-transact-sql-information (still not supported)

Answer (score 4):

FILESTREAM data type is not supported in Replication, Mirroring and Snapshots, which sucks big time, but it is what it is...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895334.aspx